# Gap in flexbox interferes with the padding of buttons

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The signup button get messed up when I add the gap or margin to add space between the two buttons. Here is a link to the code. https://jsfiddle.net/0wunbxvp/7/

The picture of the problem at hand:

[image]

```css
.header-buttons {
  max-width: 24.9rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  gap: 24px;

}

.btn-login {
  padding: 12px;
  border: 2px solid #ffc305;
  color: #ffc305;
  background-color: transparent;
  flex: 1 0 50%;
}

.btn-signup {
  flex: 1 0 50%;
  color: #010101;
  background-color: #ffc305;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #c79800;
  border-right: 4px solid #c79800;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the gap. The buttons are overflowing the div with class `.header` because the both class `.bth-login` and `.btn-signup` contain `flex: 1 0 50%` and it's the `flex-basis` of 50% that's pushing the buttons out from the edge of the container. Essentially you've said the child elements want to be 50% width of the parent plus a gap so the buttons + gap are wider than the parent container.

It appears that you're doing this to add padding to either side of the button text so if you remove the flex rule and add `padding-inline` then the buttons will move back inside the parent container. I've also added `white-space: nowrap` so the words **Sign** and **In** are kept on the same line.

If you wanted to have both buttons a fixed width then rather than using `flex:` then use `width` instead.

Hope this helps.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  line-height: 1.5;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  background-color: #010101;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.btn {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 999px;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  max-width: 144rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  
  align-items: center;
  max-height: 92px;
  padding: 16px 24px;
}

.search-bar {
  width: 400px;
  max-height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.search-bar input {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 999px;
  padding: 11px 16px;
  background-color: #171717;
  flex: 1;
}

.search-button {
  padding: 11px 24px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 999px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;

  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
}

.header-buttons {
  max-width: 24.9rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  gap: 24px;

}

.btn-login {
  padding: 12px;
  border: 2px solid #ffc305;
  color: #ffc305;
  background-color: transparent;
  /*flex: 1 0 50%;*/
  padding-inline:1rem; /*added this */
}

.btn-signup {
  /*flex: 1 0 50%;*/
  padding-inline:1rem; /*added this */
  color: #010101;
  background-color: #ffc305;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #c79800;
  border-right: 4px solid #c79800;
  white-space:nowrap; /*added this */
}
```

```html
<header>
      <div class="header container">
        <img src="https://proacetipster.com/new/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/logo.png" alt="" class="logo-header">
        <form action="" class="search-bar">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." name="q" class="search-input-field">
          <button class="search-button">Search</button>
        </form>
        <div class="header-buttons">
          <button class="btn btn-login">Login</button>
          <button class="btn btn-signup">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
    </header>
```